# Visualization of backend call and execution in a wxPython or other GUI application on Ubuntu

Tags: python, user-interface, debugging, wxpython

I have the source code of a GUI application written in wxPython. Does there exist a tool that can visualize the GUI application and its backend function? For example, if I hang my mouse over the menu or button, it can tell me which function it calls.

If this tool doesn't exist, is there any tool that can generate a tree-like report, with which it can tell me the pipeline and hierarchy of this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this purpose [wxFormBuilder](https://github.com/wxFormBuilder/wxFormBuilder) is used. However, this will work only if you have form builder setup file, source code itself will not be enough. Otherwise, unfortunately, there is no other possibility